# How to query for all tokens owned by an acoount?

Tags: api, eosio.token, scatter

Several airdrops are coming in these days. One doesn't know which tokens are gifted to them. How can I retrieve all tokens owned by a particular account? I know how to retrieve token balance, by providing token contract name and account name. The scatter web extension shows all tokens and its balance. How do they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attually, they have a list token name with token'account.

You can refer here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eoscafe/eos-airdrops/master/tokens.json

Comment: But I just want to know which tokens are gifted to me during airdrops. Question edited

Comment: Yes, they've checked the list popular token with your account.

Comment: What if the token is not popular? Is there any other way to query it?

Comment: You should know the account name who was created that token. I've check eosio.token source code, the structure is accounts accountstable( _self, owner ); .That mean, we need contract name, and account owner to quere data

Answer (score 1):

Here is example: i want to check token with this account name "bitfinexeos1"

I should check it with each contract name : eosio.token, eosadddddddd, eosdactokens, eoxeoxeoxeox ... from the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eoscafe/eos-airdrops/master/tokens.json

─$ cleos -u https://mainnet.genereos.io get table eosio.token bitfinexeos1

accounts 
{
  "rows": [{
      "balance": "52996.0725 EOS"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}

─$ cleos -u https://mainnet.genereos.io get table eosadddddddd bitfinexeos1

accounts
{
  "rows": [{
      "balance": "110.0768 ADD"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}

$ cleos -u https://mainnet.genereos.io get table eosdactokens bitfinexeos1

accounts
{
  "rows": [],
  "more": false
}